# Replying to email in gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-text-editor

I'd like to reply to an email someone sent me.  And reply inline to their email.  I'd like it to be clear what is my text and what is their text.  Is there some setting I can do which marks my text as blue as something.

My text will be interspersed with their text and if I don't have it clear whose is whose it will become  impossible to follow.

Comment: The normal way to do that is by placing a `>` in front of the text that you are replying to. Many modern email client recognise that and adjust the text colour accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

When replying, the quoted text will be indented, with a left border line running vertical to it.

If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a new line of text, your response will show up in between the quoted text, without the indentation. This should be enough to distinguish your feedback from the original.

You can also change the text color of your response, but like I mention in my comment to @tgunn, you will need to choose the color again if you are clicking around to various parts of the email in your response.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the new compose function, you first have to select all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on OS X) in  the reply window.

Now, Gmail will show you the complete original message. It'll also prepend the original message with a vertical bar:

[image]

Move your cursor after the line with "Foo bar!", and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now type your inline reply:

[image]

The reply will not be indented, and separated from the original message.

Answer (score 0):

You can always hit "Reply" select the [...] button in your reply, then before typing select a different colour - it will persist until you change it.

Comment: I actually don't think it persists. If you click around to other portions of the message you'll have to reselect the color.